# Swift: Why aren't my UITextFieldDelegate methods being called?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to programmatically create a `UITextView` and create a delegate to handle the events. I am able to create add and the `UITextView` just fine, but none of the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods are bing added.
Why would this be?

```
    let myTextField = UITextField()
    myTextField.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 100, width: 300, height: 30)
    myTextField.text = "Example Text"

    class MyTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            // Hide the keyboard.
            print("should return!\n")
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("yay!\n")
            print(textField.text! + "\n")
        }

        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            print("yay begin!\n")
            print(textField.text! + "\n")
        }

    }

    let myTextFieldDelegate = MyTextFieldDelegate()
    myTextField.delegate = myTextFieldDelegate
    scrollView.addSubview(myTextField)
```

Comment: Where is this code? Inside of `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your issue is that `myTextFieldDelegate` is freed because no one has a strong pointer to it.  Create a property in your `ViewController` to hold `myTextFieldDelegate` instead of assigning it to a local variable that will be freed when the function returns.

Comment: At first it wasn't inside of `viewDidLoad`, so I fixed that and it still wasn't working, But when I made myTextFieldDelegate a property on my custom ViewController (as to try to get it to not get garbage collected), it worked! Thank you! If you put that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UITextField`, `delegate` is declared as a `weak` property.

```
weak var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? { get set }
```

This means that it doesn't retain the `delegate` instance and will be set to `nil` when the `delegate` is freed.

You are creating the `delegate` and assigning it to a local variable `myTextFieldDelegate`.  That variable will be freed at the end of the function, so even though you assigned `myTextFieldDelegate` to the `myTextField.delegate`, it is freed and `myTextField.delegate` gets set to `nil` because it is weak.

To fix this, create a property in your `ViewController` to hold the delegate object:

```
var myTextFieldDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate?
```

Answer (score 1):

because no one retains the myTextfieldVariable... one way would be a to have an instance variable to keep a strong reference to it

Answer (score 1):

By convention, a delegate reference is weak. That prevents a retain cycle.

Thus, when you say

```
myTextField.delegate = myTextFieldDelegate
```

The text field does NOT hold an owning reference to the delegate.

If your code the creates the myDelegate object is inside a method:

```
func someFunction() {
    let myTextFieldDelegate = MyTextFieldDelegate()
    myTextField.delegate = myTextFieldDelegate
    scrollView.addSubview(myTextField)
}
```

Then the variable `myTextFieldDelegate` holds a strong reference to your newly created `MyTextFieldDelegate` object. However, the variable `myTextFieldDelegate` goes out of scope as soon as the function returns.

There are no longer **any** strong references to the `MyTextFieldDelegate` object, and so it gets deallocated.

as vacawama suggests in his comment, you need your view controller to have an instance variable that holds a strong reference:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

  //myTextFieldDelegate is now an instance variable. 
  //It will hold a strong reference.
  var myTextFieldDelegate: MyTextFieldDelegate?

  func someFunction() {
      myTextFieldDelegate = MyTextFieldDelegate()
      myTextField.delegate = myTextFieldDelegate
      scrollView.addSubview(myTextField)
  }
}
```